# When entering a Laravel command I get an error message

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I am working with a Mac (IDE PhpStorm).

When I enter the following command in the terminal area :

```
php artisan serve
```

... or

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get the following error message

> bash: php: command not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed php?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* Nothing. Your **bash** simply cannot find system-wide PHP on your computer. Type the same command in OS terminal -- does it work there? Try commands like `which php` / `whereis php` to see if you have any. If you do not have PHP -- you need to install one. If you do -- make it system wide (the path to PHP executable must be present in `PATH` environment variable). if it works in OS terminal but does not in PhpStorm's one -- the IDE does not see the full environment then.